# Why isn't my response from API displaying on page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Building an arcade search app for a school project. Im getting it to display the API info from giantbomb fine, but its not showing the info im getting from the YouTube API. Im getting the response fine from YouTube, but my JS code isnt displaying it onto my page. What did I do wrong? Its showing the giantbomb stuff fine, and it shows "you tube" `<section id="tubeResults">` but nothing underneath.

JS:

```
'use strict'

watchForm();

function watchForm(){
    $('form').submit(event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    getGameInfo();
    getTubeInfo();
    })
}

function getGameInfo(){
    var inputVal = $(".searchBox").val();

    const searchUrl = `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://www.giantbomb.com/api/search/?api_key=[API-KEY-HERE]&format=json&query=${inputVal}&field_list=name,platforms,image,deck&resource_type=game`;

    fetch(searchUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(newResponse => {
        console.log(newResponse);

        return newResponse;
    })
    .then(newResponse => displayResults(newResponse, inputVal))
}

function displayResults(newResponse) {

    let filteredResults = newResponse.results.filter(
        item =>
          item.platforms &&
          item.platforms.find(platform => platform.name === "Arcade")
      );
      console.log(filteredResults);

    $('#results-list').empty();

    for(let i = 0; i < filteredResults.length; i++) {
        $('#results-list').append(
            `<li>
            <h2>${filteredResults[i].name}</h2>
            <input type="image" src="${filteredResults[i].image.thumb_url}">
            <h3>${filteredResults[i].deck}</h3>
            </li>`)
    }
    $('#results').removeClass('hidden')
}

function getTubeInfo(){
    var inputVal = $(".searchBox").val();

    const searchUrl = `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q="${inputVal}+Arcade+Gameplay"&key=[API-KEY-HERE]`;

    fetch(searchUrl)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(tubeResponse => {
        console.log(tubeResponse);

        return tubeResponse;
    })
    .then(tubeResponse => displayTube(tubeResponse, inputVal))
}

function displayTube(tubeResponse){
    $('#results-list2').empty();

    for(let i = 0; i < tubeResponse.length; i++) {
        $('#results-list2').append(
            `<li>
            <h3>${tubeResponse.items[i].snippet.title}</h3>
            <p>${tubeResponse.items[i].snippet.description}</p>
            <img src='${tubeResponse.items[i].snippet.thumbnails.default.url}'>
            </li>`)
    }
    $('#tubeResults').removeClass('hidden')

}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>Arcade Game Search Zone</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
        integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to the Arcade Game Search Zone</h1>
        <p>Looking for information on a specific Arcade game? Search for one below to recieve information, videos and wiki</p>
        <form>
            <input class="searchBox" type="text" value="Donkey Kong">
            <input class="submitButton" type="submit">
        </form>

        <section id="results" class="hidden info">
            <h2>Search Results</h2>
            <ul id="results-list">
            </ul>
        </section>

        <section id="tubeResults" class="hidden tube">
            <h2>You Tube</h2>
            <ul id="results-list2">
            </ul>
        </section> 


        <script src="script.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What is the debugger telling you? Are there any errors in the console? Does your `fetch()` work? Please give us more information about how you have been debugging the code.

Comment: Ive been using console.logs to debug. No errors in console and I'm getting back complete info from API

Comment: fetch() is working fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is just a simple typo. We have here:

```
for(let i = 0; i < tubeResponse.length; i++) {
```

However, this should be:

```
for(let i = 0; i < tubeResponse.items.length; i++) {
```

The console window should have output an error about `tubeResponse.length` being undefined.